# Possible properties of Varnish objects

Tags: varnish

I can not for the life of me find any documentation regarding the possible properties of varnish (version 3) objects.

We know (from googling, varnish documentation just mumbles and leaves you more frustrated) for example that the request object has the url property (req.url) and also that it has req.http.X-Forwarded-For. But has anyone ever in any way found... say... a list?

Thanks!

/joakim

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't really give a comprehensive list of things like `req.http.X-Forwarded-For` because `req.http.*` are HTTP headers. The `Cookie` header of a request will be `req.http.Cookie` and the `User-Agent` header will be `req.http.User-Agent`. There are a lot of standard headers, but you can set any arbitrary header and it will show up in `req.http.___________`. You can see the headers of the HTTP **response** in `resp.http.*`. Same for backend response in `beresp.http.*`.

All of the other properties are listed here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#variables